# Return a value from nested jquery function

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code to check if a name exists.
However, I cannot get the return value whether true or false for further validation. How can I get the return value from this function?

```
function check_availability() //check auction name if exists
        {
        var new_Auction =$('#txtAuction').val();
        $.post('checkAuction.php',{txtAuc:$('#txtAuction').val()},
            function(result){
                if(new_Auction.length==0)
                {
                    $('#message').html('');
                }
                else
                {
                if(result==1)
                {
                    $('#message').html(new_Auction + ' is Available').css('color','#0C3');
                    $('input[id=btnCreate]').removeAttr('Disabled');
                 //$('h4.alert_success').css("display","block");
                 //$('h4.alert_success').html(new_Auction + ' is Available');  
                 //$('h4.alert_success').fadeOut(5000); 
                return true;

                }
                 else
                 {

                    $('#message').html(new_Auction + ' is not Available').css('color','#F00');
                    $('input[id=btnCreate]').attr('Disabled','Disabled');
                    //$('h4.alert_error').css("display","block"); 
                    //$('h4.alert_error').html(new_Auction + ' is not available'); 
                    return false;
                 }
                }
            }
        );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is *asynchronous*. You can't return from a callback to an asynchronous call. Move the code the relies upon the result of that AJAX call to inside the callback instead of trying to return from it.

```
$.post('checkAuction.php', {txtAuc:$('#txtAuction').val()}, function(result){
    //You cannot return a value from in here!
});
```

When you make an asynchronous request, execution continues with the next statement, so there would be nowhere for control to "return" to when it executes the async callback some time later.

Comment: then is there any ways i can can get to validate this together with other jquery return functions?